# how to make the border of a text field change color differently only when the cursor is inside flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to change the color of the border but only when the cursor is in the text field but I used a container widget to edit the borders of the text field. I also want to put a padding to the right in the text field to make the hint text in the text field look better. But when I try to make all those changes, the padding affects the outline input border. This is what I have presently: [This is exactly how I want it to look, but only with the cursor inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNBJ9.png)

This is my code:

```
// email adress text field
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: "youremail@example.com",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your textfield widget with InkWell and pass setState() into onHover method, which will be updating yours textfield borders, when users mouse entering in textField space

```
late bool _isHovering;

@override
void initState()
{
_isHovering = false;
}

InkWell(
child: Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   border: Border.all(color: _isHovering ? Colors.green : Colors.grey.shade600),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
 child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
         border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          hintText: "youremail@example.com",), ),),,
  onTap: () {
    //Leave it empty, like that.
  }
  onHover: (isHovering) {
      _setState(() {_isHovering = isHovering;});
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you but the colors did not change on hover. It's the default blue

Answer (score 0):

This example will change border colors when you click on text field

```
TextField(
          controller: messageTextFieldController,
          obscureText: false,
          maxLines: null,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Write a message...',
            isDense: true,
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.amber),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Where did the controller come from?

Comment: messageTextFieldController  That just a text controller, use your own controller what ever you name it